# Как пройти полный цикл, используя функцию

Tags: python, функции

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть функция 'find_names', она выдает лишь 1 имя из строки 'str'.

```
str = 'names: "Ivan", "Petr", "Nikolai"'
names_list = ['Ivan', 'Petr']
list = []
def find_names(string):
    for i in string.split():
        for n in names_list:
            if "names" in str:
                if n in i:
                    list.append(n)
                    return list
find_names(str)
```

Eсли пишут тот же код, но без функции, получаю полный список имен.

```
str = 'names: "Ivan", "Petr", "Nikolai"'
names_list = ['Ivan', 'Petr']
list = []
for i in str.split():
    for n in names_list:
        if "names" in str:
            if n in i:
                list.append(n)
print(list)
```

Comment: Потому что `return` завершает функцию

Comment: `return list` нужно делать не на одном уровне с `append` (внутри внетреннего `if`), а на одном уровне с внешним `for` (снаружи всех циклов и `if`) - т.е. выход делать только когда все циклы выполнятся, а не после нахождения первого элемента.

Comment: я вообще не вижу в коде функцию get_names.

Comment: Лучше не называйте переменные именами [встроенных функций](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions), таких как `list`, а то не сможете ими пользоваться, например `print(list("1234"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну так вы после первого условия сразу делаете `return` и выходите из функции

```
def find_names(string):
    for i in string.split():
        for n in names_list:
            if "names" in str:
                if n in i:
                    list.append(n) # записываем в list первое значение
                    return list # и тут же выходим из цикла
```

Просто сделайте выход из функции не в цикле:

```
def find_names(string):
    for i in string.split():
        for n in names_list:
            if "names" in str:
                if n in i:
                    list.append(n)

    return list
```

и все будет в порядке

Comment: Но всё же надо было добавить, что `list` и `str` - это плохие имена для переменных )

Comment: это безусловно!!!

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо внутри функции `return` заменить на `print`, чтобы у вас произошёл вывод, а не возврат переменной с последующим завершением функции

```
str = 'names: "Ivan", "Petr", "Nikolai"'
names_list = ['Ivan', 'Petr']
list = []

def find_names(string):
    for i in str.split():
        for n in names_list:
            if "names" in str:
                if n in i:
                    list.append(n)
    print(list)

find_names(str)
```

Comment: @insolor не цепляйтесь к словам. Если есть какие-то замечания, то можете внести свою правку. И размышления кабы да если бы я бы не стал рассматривать, т.к. с такими размышлениями можно половину кода в вопросах переписывать

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, при таком сценарии использовании функции можно и вообще без `return` и переменной-списка обойтись:

```
str_ = 'names: "Ivan", "Petr", "Nikolai"'
names_list = ['Ivan', 'Petr']

def find_names(string):
    for i in string.split():
        for n in names_list:
            if "names" in str_:
                if n in i:
                    yield n

print(list(find_names(str_)))
```